# How to change the values of Grading method dropdown in Moodle 2.6

Tags: php, moodle

Thanks in advance,

I have some customer requirements to change Moodle grade into score(literally the keyword).

I've tried to find the Grading method dropdown (present in "moodle/course/modedit.php") in database and the also in the code but unfortunately did't got the solution.

below mentioned is my findings of some presets in moodle\mod\quiz\lib.php

```
/**#@+
 * Options determining how the grades from individual attempts are 
 combined to give
* the overall grade for a user
*/
define('QUIZ_GRADEHIGHEST', '1');
define('QUIZ_GRADEAVERAGE', '2');
define('QUIZ_ATTEMPTFIRST', '3');
define('QUIZ_ATTEMPTLAST',  '4');
/**#@-*/
```

and in moodle\mod\quiz\mod_form.php

```
$mform->addElement('select', 'grademethod', get_string('grademethod', 
'quiz'),quiz_get_grading_options());
```

need to know where it comes from?

```
function quiz_get_grading_options() {
    /*
    return array(
        QUIZ_GRADEHIGHEST => get_string('gradehighest', 'quiz'),
        QUIZ_GRADEAVERAGE => get_string('gradeaverage', 'quiz'),
        QUIZ_ATTEMPTFIRST => get_string('attemptfirst', 'quiz'),
        QUIZ_ATTEMPTLAST  => get_string('attemptlast', 'quiz')
    );
    */
    // Commented and added by sherin on 07/05/2019
    return array('Highest score','Average score','First attempt','Last 
attempt');
}
```

I've edited the existing return array in the above mentioned function(present in mod\quiz\locallib.php) and it finally worked, do some one know where the actual data is comes from?

```
 QUIZ_GRADEHIGHEST => get_string('gradehighest', 'quiz')
```

Hope you guys understand the problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sherin... If I understand your question correctly, I think you need to change the language file that is in the 'lang' directory.

In the path /mod/quiz/lang/ (/en/, /es/,... and so for each language you have installed) there is a php file with all the words that are displayed. If you do not find the files in that route, are probably located in the moodledata.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
I've looked into the specified file and removed entire content from it but there was no effect on my page and changed moodledata to moodledata1 then also same.